# how to update value from a selected option of dropdown list?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

how to update value from a selected option of dropdown list PHP MySQL:

So I'm trying to do this wherein as I click the submit button, it will update set_default in my MySQL table to 1 and that will become the quiz while the default quiz will be overwritten by it and its value will be set to 0.

```
        <form  method="POST" action="index.php">

        <select name="data">

        <?php echo $options;?>

    </select>


        <input type="submit" name="defaultQuiz" value="Set Quiz"   >
            </form>
 <?php

if(isset($_POST['defaultQuiz'])&& $_POST['defaultQuiz'] != ""){
    $defaultQ = $_POST['data'];
      require_once("scripts/connect_db.php");

    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE quizes SET set_default=0 WHERE set_default=1")or 
    die(mysqli_error($db));
    mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE quizes SET set_default=1 WHERE quiz_name='$defaultQ'")or die(mysqli_error($db));


    $defaultQ_sql1 = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT id FROM quizes WHERE set_default=1")or die(mysqli_error($db));

    $numDefaults = mysqli_num_rows($defaultQ_sql1);

    if($numDefaults < 1 || $numDefaults > 1){
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem setting /".$defaultQ."/ default. Please try again later.";
        exit();
    }else{
        echo "Thanks! The quiz, /".$defaultQ."/ has now been set as default.";
        exit();
    }
}
```

However, I always get the error message "Sorry there was a problem setting $defaultQ. default..
I've tried to change the code several times but I'm sure the problem lies within the

```
mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE quizes SET set_default=0 WHERE set_default=1")
   or die(mysqli_error($db));
mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE quizes SET set_default=1 WHERE quiz_name='$defaultQ'")
   or die(mysqli_error($db));
```

function

Comment: if($numDefaults < 1 || $numDefaults > 1)  problem is with statement. Kindly remove $numDefaults>1 .

Comment: Removed $numDefaults>1 and same problem. Thank you anyways

Comment: Kindly check into your database that query is updating the value or not?

Comment: I checked and unfortunately it didn't. What its actually doing is just ignoring the first if statement after $numdefaults and proceeds to echo else statement, without actually changing/updating value in database. Thankyou!

Comment: Can you post the code of connect_db.php?

Comment: So, have you made sure that you actually have data with `set_default=1` in your table? What does `$defaultQ` contain? Or `<?php echo $options;?>`?

Comment: Yes I do have data with set_default=1 in my table. $defaultQ contains the quizzes which $options are actually pertaining to, it is showing it in a dropdown list.

Comment: Actually updated <?php echo $options;?> to <?php while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row2[2];?>"><?php echo $row2[2];?></option>

            <?php endwhile;?>

        </select> though both works the same It's just that the problem lies within the mysqli_query or after that, Thank you!